# Changing indexes to prove $\Lambda_{ij}=-\Lambda_{ji} \implies \sum_{i,j=1 , i\neq j}^N \Lambda_{ij} =0$.

Tags: summation, index-notation

We want to prove, for an $N\times N$ matrix $\Lambda$,

$$\Lambda_{ji}=-\Lambda_{ij}\implies\sum_{i,j=1 ; i\neq j}^N \Lambda_{ij}=0$$

My approach:

$$\sum_{i,j=1 ; i\neq j}^N \Lambda_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^N\left[\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ij}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ij}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}-\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ji}$$

Here, an appropriate change of indexes is needed to make the two sums identical so that we can merge them together and achieve a sum of zeros which equals zero.

But I cannot find that smart change of indexes. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  is a calculation according to OPs approach  avoiding also empty sums.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{{i,j=1}\atop{ i\neq j}}^N \Lambda_{ij}}
> &=\sum_{i=\color{blue}{2}}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^{\color{blue}{N-1}}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ij}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}-\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ji}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}-\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum_{i=j+1}^{N}\Lambda_{ij}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}-\sum_{1\leq j<i\leq N}\Lambda_{ij}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}-\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Lambda_{ij}\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we respect $1\leq i\ne j\leq n$ by setting the lower limit $i=2$ in the left sum and the upper limit $N-1$ in the right sum of the RHS.
- In (2) we apply $\Lambda_{ij}=-\Lambda_{ji}$.
- In (3) we exchange indices $i$ and $j$ in the right sum.
- In (4) we use another notation of the index range which is helpful when exchanging the summation symbols.
- In (5) we exchange the summation of the right sum.

Comment: very comprehensive! so the main ideal lies in the inequality notation in step 4. yes?

Comment: @AHB: Thanks! The main idea is to exchange the sums, but this preparatory representation makes the exchange much easier. This way we can most clearly see the relationship between $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply relabeling $(i,j)$ by $(j,i)$, we have

$$ \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^{N} \Lambda_{ij}
\stackrel{\text{relabeling}}{=} \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^{N} \Lambda_{ji}
\stackrel{\text{antisymmetry}}{=} - \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^{N} \Lambda_{ij}. $$

Since the sum is its own negative, it must reduce to zero.

Comment: yes, and it is even simpler, but I wanted to use this separation and re-merging method, because I believe it can work in some places where  this short method will not work.

Comment: @AHB, The basic idea is that the given relation $\Lambda_{ij}+\Lambda_{ji} = 0$ naturally gives rise to a partition of the range of indices $\{(i,j) : i,j\in[n], \ i\neq j\}$. Separating the sum as in your trial is simply splitting the sum by choosing different representatives from each partition, and my solution is just permuting representatives in each equivalence relation. In essence, two tricks are not so different. But I agree that possibly one is more suited than other depending on situation. In your case, you can swap the order of summation to complete your solution.

Answer (score 2):

A rather different approach: $\Lambda$ is clearly a matrix which is the negative of its own transpose. If $u$ is a vector of all $1$s, then $$
q = u^t \Lambda u$$
 is the sum you're computing on the right, except that $q$ includes the sum of the $\Lambda_{ii}$ terms...but those are all zero, so $q$ is equal to the sum you want to compute.

Now look at $q^t$ (which is just $q$, because it's just a number). We have
\begin{align}
q + q &= q + q^t \\
&= u^t \Lambda u + u^t \Lambda^t u \\ 
&= u^t (\Lambda + \Lambda^t) u  \\
&= u^t {\mathbf 0 } u  \\
&= 0 
\end{align}
whence $q = 0$. No indices needed at all. Of course, the whole argument can be written out with indices as well, but once you've done the summation-swapping to prove that matrix multiply is associative, why re-do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=j+1}^N = \sum\limits_{1 \leq j < i \leq N} = \sum\limits_{i=2}^N \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{i-1}
$$

Comment: I cannot understand the approach. can you continue from my last line?